# DHCP over Frame Relay

Tags: cisco, switch, dhcp, frame-relay

I have two co-operate buildings. Building A is connected to building B via frame relay. Building A has the main switch server (with VLAN info) and a DHCP server. I need Building B devices to receive DHCP IP addresses and client switches to update trunks on VLANs from the server switch. How do I do this over frame relay? Using Cisco Packet Tracer.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  You don't say what kind of addressing scheme you're using, nor whether you have any routers.  To get DHCP requests from B to server at A, the usual way is with `ip helper-address DHCPSERVERADDR` on B's router's LAN interface, but that presumes several things about routing and addressing.

Comment: We need to see a diagram of your network as well as relevant device configurations.  Most of us here don't have Packet Tracer.

Comment: Hello!
my setup is
DHCP server --> server switch --> edge router A --> Frame Relay --> edge router B --> client switch --> PC

DHCP have several pool of net work 172.16.0.0 broadcasting ip on 5 different vlans.
I tried using ip helper-address.
If i manually put IP on PC in Building B, i can ping all devices including DHCP server in Building A

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requested information.